# Can XUI create swipe, slide and fade transitions?

Tags: cordova, xui

I'm trying to build a phonegap application that I hope to work on blackberry OS6+, iOS 4+ and android 2.2+ devices.  I'm taking a look at XUI.JS as the javascript library.  Does XUI offer me the tools to easily create swiping, sliding and fading effects?  If so, can someone show me functional code as an example?  I don't see full examples on the XUI website.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a swipe plugin for XUI at [github.com/xui/xui-plugins/tree/master/swipe](https://github.com/xui/xui-plugins/tree/master/swipe) which you can use to detect swipe and tap actions. You can then add effects using the `.tween()` method.

Answer (score 1):

also, if you want to use a very cool swipe library called TouchSwipe (made for JQuery) with XUI, you can use this XUI plugin from Matt Bryson: https://github.com/cowgp/xui-touchSwipe